# Getting HTTP/1.1" 500 27 when debug set to FALSE in my django local environment

Tags: python, django

I have the settings.py like below

Basically our DEBUG will be set to TRUE. But since to the production we need to set FALSE, we have to handle the code to set debug FALSE. even with debug=FALSE the app should work as it is.

But in my case, because debug is set to FALSE , my app is giving  HTTP/1.1" 500 27 error.

I have followed many answers but didnt understand what can suite exactly to my issue. please let me know if anyone has the proper answer to this like what changes needs to be added here.

```
 import os
 BASE_DIR = 
 os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
 SECRET_KEY = os.environ["DJANGO_SECRET_KEY"]'
 DEBUG = False
 ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
 INSTALLED_APPS = [
 'MyApp',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',    
 ]
 TEMPLATES = [
  {
      'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
      'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
      'APP_DIRS': True,
'OPTIONS': {
    'context_processors': [
        'django.template.context_processors.debug',
        'django.template.context_processors.request',
        'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
        'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    ],
    },
    },
    ]
  MIDDLEWARE = [
  'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
  ]
```

Comment: You should attach log files/error traceback to your question

Comment: log file has something like this "
"GET graphway=hour&fromdate=11%2F14%2F2021+00%3A00+-+11%2F30%2F2021+23%3A59&Error_Report=Error_Report&Utili_Report=Utili_Report&fromdate_H=03%2F16%2F2022+00%3A00+-+03%2F16%2F2022+23%3A59 HTTP/1.1" 500 27
"   this is the latest erro thatt i got, couldnt post the entire log file since some are secrets

Comment: We can't help you based on information you have provided, 500 status code means that something in your code went wrong. Couldn't you delete secret information from stack trace?